# Get Individual App Battery Usage iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, battery, batterylevel

I want to know if there is any way I can get the percentage of battery usage for each app used by the user in iOS using Swift 2. It is like in `Settings > Battery` and there will be a battery usage group. Please help

Comment: This may be useful: https://github.com/ethan605/ios-battery-stat

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no simple "show me a battery usage breakdown by app" option. It is quite complex to figure out what factors lead to battery drain.

Comment: In iOS9, this information is available. See http://ios.wonderhowto.com/how-to/view-battery-usage-stats-for-individual-apps-your-iphone-ios-8-0155302/  

What I'm wondering is how to access that data through another app. Is that accessible?