# Power consumption of an iOS application

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, instruments

I want check power usage of my iOS application.
I tried with the Instruments.

In the 'Energy Usage Level' it shows values 1/20 (0 to 20),indicating how much energy your app is using at any given time.

What the value meant 0 to 20?.
And how Can I export the value in to text document

**Edit :**  How can I convert it to percentage of energy usage ?

Answer (score 1):

What Apple mentioned is [the following](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/EnergyGuide-iOS/MonitorEnergyWithInstruments.html) :

> The Energy Usage instrument shows a level from 0 to 20, indicating how
>   much energy your app is using at a given time. These numbers are
>   subjective. If your app’s energy usage level is occasionally high, it
>   doesn’t necessarily mean that your app has a problem. Your app may
>   simply require more energy for some of the tasks it performs. For
>   example, it may use GPS while performing complex network operations.
>   This is valid energy use. What you should look for are spikes or areas
>   of high energy use that are unexpected or that could be performed at
>   more optimal times.

the numbers are subjective it just can be used as an indicator on how high your usage is, thats all.

the link also provides a way to log the energy usage level.

Comment: Is there any way to find the battery % used my application ?

Comment: Sorry couldn't find anything useful about that, here are other questions that have dead end too 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32819490/get-individual-app-battery-usage-ios

Comment: if my answer helped please set it as accepted answer since there is no better answer exists :)

Comment: I have asked this question based on the documentation as your answer. But, My questiion is what exact the values 0 to 20 indicates ?

Comment: @VineeshTP Disclaimer, I'm one of the sr. engineers at GameBench

Our Desktop App that records performance metrics like FPS, CPU, GPU etc is currently in a closed beta for recording iOS power in mA.

You can shoot us an email if you're looking to try it.